# Selecting Table Row using Struts2 tag

Tags: jsp, html-table, struts2

I am new to Struts 2 , please help me with the below scenario

I have a table in Jsp using struts2  tag , All I Want to do is to retrieve the selected(checked) table row's value in the action class.

Please let me know how to achieve it .

---

Below is the code requested

```
<s:iterator value="listOfDtos" status="stat">
<tr>
<td><s:checkbox name="delete" value="select" /></td>
<td><s:property value="FirstName"/></td>
<td><s:property value="LastName"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
<s:submit id="delete" value="delete"/>
```

"`listOfDtos`" is an array list of `dto` and is set in the action like the below

```
ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().set("listOfDtos", listOfDtos);
```

Now when the user selects any row to be deleted I want to be able to first of all retrieve this list of dtos in the Action and iterate them to check which of the `dtos` have the attribute "`select`" set to true.

"`select`" is an attribute of type String in the dto.

How can this be done ? also how will the "`listOfDtos`" be made available in the Action.

Comment: Please post the jsp code along with the question.

Comment: It will be really more easy for other to answer your question if you can provide you code

Comment: Please take look into the below code

Answer (score 0):

you can use that....

```
<s:iterator var="something" id="something"  value="something" status="ListStatus">
            <s:if test="#ListStatus.index == 0">
                <tr  style="border: 1px solid black;" bgcolor="lightgray" height="20">
                    <td  align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;"><s:checkbox id ="itemToDelete1" name="checkAll" onchange=" check(main_form.fileNames,this.checked)"/></td>
                    <td  align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;"><strong>INSTANCE ID</strong></td>
                    <td  align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;"><strong>FILE NAME</strong></td>
                    <td  align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;"><strong>SUB DT</strong></td>
                    <td  align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;"><strong>PROCESS STATUS</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </s:if>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
                <td  align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;"><s:checkbox id ="itemToDelete" name="fileNames" fieldValue="%{#fileDetails.fileName}"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><s:property value="#fileDetails.fileInstId"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><s:property value="#fileDetails.fileName"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><s:property value="#fileDetails.dataOfSubmission"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><s:property value="#fileDetails.fileProcessStatus"/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
```

I have used it and it is working very fine....
As you can see if you check the headers checkbox it will select all checkboxes. 
now this is the field you need in your action class fileDetails.fileName
I hope you get some help by this.....

Answer (score -1):

Is the function you're doing is to delete a specific row when the check box of the row is checked?

You can try to put an href on the row with a variable referenced to a data in the certain row.

E.g.

```
<a href="deleteuser.action?id=<s:property value="id"/>&action=delete"/>delete </a>
```

This is the code I'm using.